# Using intent to get to another page however app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to create a game. I have made the start screen which has two buttons. The play button and the settings button. When I press the settings button the game works fine, however when I click the play button the app crashes.

```
package com.example.android.clashofthemathtitans;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String grade = "1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);
        final Button settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(StartPage.this, Settings.class);
                startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, 1);
            }
        });

        final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent playIntent = new Intent(StartPage.this, Play.class);
                startActivity(playIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            grade= data.getStringExtra("Spinner Value");
            final TextView grade_text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grade);
            grade_text_view.setText(grade);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try using play, the app shuts down. I don't understand why. When I press the settings button it works perfectly fine.What is wrong?

Comment: You should add logcat so other can help you out.

Comment: Post your manifest and look at the content of the logcat. You'll probably see the reason for your crash.

Answer (score 1):

play.class doesn't look like it's registering the class. Notice how Settings.class and StartPage.class are highlighted. Check if you spelled it right.

Comment: I made sure that now the Play.class is highlighted. However it still doesn't work.

Comment: Look at your Logcat and post the exception your receiving?

Answer (score 0):

check this line:

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(StartPage.this, play.class); //its probably Play.class
```

Comment: Probably not. It wouldn't compile if that were the case.